# Multiple GET requests to a single site (canonical) (java)

Tags: java, cookies, get

Hi I am trying to make 2 GET requests to a single connection. ie

```
HttpGet get1 = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/search?q=HelloWorld");
HttpGet get2 = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/search?q=SecondSearch");

HttpResponse response = null;

response = client.execute(get1);
response = client.execute(get2);
```

I would like to get the body from the second execution. Obviously this fails, because it says you must release the connection first. I need to maintain the exact session - for instance, if I navigate to a site where the first step is to login, I need to navigate to any subsequent pages with the same cookie.

It's probably something incredibly simple that I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [CookieStore](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html)

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

DefaultHttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
client1.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
HttpGet httpGet1 = new HttpGet("...");
HttpResponse response1 = client1.execute(httpGet1);

DefaultHttpClient client2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
client2.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
HttpGet httpGet2 = new HttpGet("...");
HttpResponse response2 = client2.execute(httpGet2);
```

In the above code, both client2 will re-use cookies from the client1 request.

Comment: amazing. thank you!
I also noticed that I can actually:

1) execute a get
2) get a bufferedstream from the first request
3) close the bufferedstream, which triggers the disconnect
4) execute the second get
5) gets the information accordingly.

but cookie management is a much cleaner way of doing things, as you have shown. thank you

Comment: actually, i've downloaded the latest httpclient from apache, and it doesn't seem to contain
HttpClient.SetCookieStore for some reason

Comment: It's not in the HttpClient interface, it's a member of AbstractHttpClient (which is parent to DefaultHttpClient).